# Setting up modern OpenGL with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I have been coding OpenGL for a while now using Java and LWJGL. However recently I decided that I would switch from Java to C++.

I managed to set up OpenGL with Visual Studio 2013, and had some fun with that. However I am used to using modern OpenGL (shaders, vbo's, vao's etc...), and I believe what I am looking for is OpenGL ES.

I have been using the GLFW library to create a window with OpenGL context, so how do I do this with OpenGL ES.

I tried adding the `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_ES31` line to above the `glfw3.h` include, however then it cannot find the `GLES3/gl31.h` header file. I don't know how to obtain this file on my computer, because the `GL/gl.h` file was just on my computer by default.

Am I supposed to download it?

---

Apparently OpenGL ES is aimed at smartphones or less powerful devices, so I was wrong in thinking I wanted to use OpenGL ES. In that case, how can I use these newer functions within Visual Studio, and C++. At the moment I only seem to have access to OpenGL 1.1 functions.

Comment: You don't need ES for shaders and buffer objects; regular OpenGL supports those just fine.  ES is a lightweight subset aimed at things like smartphones.

Comment: Does no one have an answer for this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking a loader ([GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for example)

"just" add it to your project and you will be able to use the GL_ functions again